# Check the convexity of the upper bounding function of the subgradient method

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

I want to proof that the function

$$
U(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k) = \frac{R^2 + M^2 \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i^2}{2 \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i}
$$

is convex, for $R, M \geq 0$ and $\alpha_i > 0$. This function is the bound of $f_\text{best}^{(k)} - f_\star$ of the subgradient method mentioned [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/subgrad_method_notes.pdf), but the text just states that the function is convex and I'm having trouble proving it.

Comment: I find this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965381/is-the-function-sum-of-squares-sum-convex-on-nonnegative-input#:~:text=Yes%2C%20it%20is%20convex), maybe can help to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your function as
$$U(\alpha) = \frac{R^2}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i} + \frac{M^2}{2} \cdot \frac{\|\alpha\|_2^2}{\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i},\: \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^k,$$
and then prove convexity for $f(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i}$ and $g(\alpha) = \frac{\|\alpha\|_2^2}{\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i}$. For $f$ you can calculate the Hessian or use induction. For $g$, you can use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965381/is-the-function-sum-of-squares-sum-convex-on-nonnegative-input#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20it%20is%20convex) as pointed by @ErlonKelvim. Since multiplying by a positive constant preserves convexity and the sum of convex functions is again convex, the result follows.